# What's the matter with the Configuration Manager dialog box in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

See below my starting point in VS2017. I have 4 projects with the same C++ code. Project `4` is the current selected startup code. I also show the Configuration Manager dialog box, showing the same Configuration/Platform, `Release/Win32` for all projects in the solution.

[image: First Configuration Manager dialog box]

Now if I change the Active solution configuration in the dialog box to `Debug` that is what I get for each project:

[image: New Configuration Manager dialog box]

Where did the platform x64 come from, in the new Configuration Manager dialog box?

**Solution file**:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28307.902
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "0", "0\0.vcxproj", "{C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "1", "1\1.vcxproj", "{28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "2", "2\2.vcxproj", "{E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "3", "3\3.vcxproj", "{2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "4", "4\4.vcxproj", "{888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {C5F36068-3D2B-4660-B5ED-2F194A07F075}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {28C914BE-5BA4-4C32-9B9E-B88AA414F346}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {E40FB7E6-2D06-423C-87CD-117075438D24}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {2BB98E5B-1D14-4544-BB03-B180FEBC488A}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {888A27C8-8FD7-4401-B034-C6FFAA00141E}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {F798085A-D102-4837-A5C7-CFC4CE56C4BC}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Share the solution file

Comment: @SolidMercury See the solution file above.

Comment: As you can see in the XML data of solution file Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64 and Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64, both debug x86 and x64 under solution are pointing to Debug x64 in the projects. You must have accidentally changed it in the drop down options because by default, it will be mapped correctly.

Comment: @Amy Thanks for your edit. How did you do that?

Comment: @Alexander By 'that', do you mean the edit itself, or how I formatted the .sln?  Where it says "edit X minutes ago" by me, click on that link.  You can see the edit.  Look at the "side by side markdown" view.

Comment: @SolidMercury I'm trying to understand what you said. From the solution file above I have for project `0` (the first project) the following: `Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32`, `Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64`, `Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64` and `Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32`. Could explain what do they mean?

Comment: @Alexander It's really late here 11:08pm and texting this from phone. I will explain that in detail on what each of those key value means tomorrow.

Comment: @SolidMercury Thank you

Comment: @SolidMercury I think I have now a pretty good understanding about what you said yesterday with one single exception. Consider the first item I mentioned yesterday on my comment, `Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32`, it is followed by `Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Win32`, in the solution file. What is this for? It seems to me to be superfluous.

Comment: @SolidMercury I've got everything now. Thanks for the help.